# Разная длина одинаковых строк в одной кодировке

Tags: php

Беру yml-файл с помощью `file_get_contents()`, достаю из него названия товаров и сравниваю с данными в БД. Совпадений как бы нет.

Окей, вывожу сами строки, их длину `strlen()` и кодировки `mb_detect_encoding()`.
Строки 'Пылесос Vitek VT-1810' одинаковы, кодировки тоже (UTF-8, она же задана в получаемом файле, mysql и вообще везде, где только можно), а вот длина разная, 85 и 28 соответственно.

`$name` — название из получаемого файла, `$wtf` — название из БД, на обеих строках использован `trim`.

- `strcmp('Пылесос Vitek VT-1810',$wtf)` - выдаёт 0
- `strcmp('Пылесос Vitek VT-1810',$name)` – почему-то 148.

Пробовал использовать `curl` — ничего не меняется.

Comment: не знаю поможет или нет, но я для русских строк считаю символы так:
mb_strlen('Пылесос Vitek VT-1810', 'UTF8');//21символ

Comment: Пробовал, выводит 78 и 21.

Comment: было подобное, что сервер мне отдавал данные в cp1251, и я их перекодировывал через iconv, тогда все ок было...

Comment: Тоже пробовал, и тоже ничего не меняется :(

Comment: Для начала возьмите и скорируйте (прям копи-паст) в ваш вопрос три строки: 'Пылесос Vitek VT-1810', значение $wtf и значение $name. Т.е. где-то в коде сделайте echo этих переменных.

Comment: `var_dump` для обеих переменных приведите

Comment: У одинаковых строк не может быть разная длина. Выведите их побайтно (можно даже hex-значения байтов для наглядности) и увидите разницу.